# Python pandas print week day name of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

somehow I got dates of the all Mondays, Tuesday and Fridays beginning a specific date for up to next year. Next, I want to print name of the weekday in the next column

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':pd.date_range(start='11/07/2022',
                                freq=week_day,end='11/07/2023')}) for week_day in ['W-MON','W-TUE','W-FRI']])
df = df.sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

      Date
0   2022-11-07
1   2022-11-08
2   2022-11-11

df['Weekday_name'] = df['Date'].strftime('%A')
```

Expected output:

```
      Date        Weekday_name
0   2022-11-07      Monday
1   2022-11-08      Tuesday
2   2022-11-11      Friday
```

Present output:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: Your forgot the `.dt` accessor: `.dt.strftime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date accessor, .dt:

```
df['weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%A')
```

Output:

```
          Date  weekday
0   2022-11-07   Monday
1   2022-11-08  Tuesday
2   2022-11-11   Friday
3   2022-11-14   Monday
4   2022-11-15  Tuesday
..         ...      ...
153 2023-10-30   Monday
154 2023-10-31  Tuesday
155 2023-11-03   Friday
156 2023-11-06   Monday
157 2023-11-07  Tuesday

[158 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['Weekday_name'] = df.Date.apply(lambda t: t.strftime('%A'))
```